# Relative positioning of Graphics2D objects on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I am making a GUI with Swing and would like to configure the Graphics2D objects with relative positioning.  I want to do this in a way that when I resize the window the objects are repainted in a new location relative to the initial anchor position (probably in the top left corner somewhere).  I have tried using layout managers to do this  but it doesn't impact the actual drawing because the points are pretty much hard coded.

What is the best way to do this?  Can anyone provide an good example?  Thanks.

Here is my self contained example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DrawPanelMain extends JPanel {

    public static final double version = 0.0;
    private JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel switchPanel = new JPanel();
    private JScrollPane switchPanelScrollPane = new JScrollPane(switchPanel);
    //private JPanel[] panelArray = new JPanel[3];

    DrawEllipses drawEllipses = new DrawEllipses(POINT_LIST);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                initializePointList();
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

    public static java.util.List<Point> POINT_LIST = new ArrayList<>();

    /*
    * This loop will initialize POINT_LIST with the set of points for drawing the ellipses.
    * The for each loop initializes points for the top row and the second for loop draws the
    * right triangle.
    */
    private static void initializePointList() {

        int ellipsePointsYCoordinate[] = {140, 200, 260, 320, 380, 440, 500, 560, 620};
        int ellipsePointsXCoordinate[] = {140, 200, 260, 320, 380, 440, 500, 560, 620, 680};
        int xx = 80;

        for (int aXt : ellipsePointsXCoordinate) {
            POINT_LIST.add(new Point(aXt, xx));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ellipsePointsYCoordinate.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < ellipsePointsYCoordinate.length; j++) {
                POINT_LIST.add(new Point(ellipsePointsXCoordinate[i], ellipsePointsYCoordinate[j]));
            }
        }
    }

    public DrawPanelMain() {

        switchPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredSoftBevelBorder());
        switchPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        switchPanel.add(drawEllipses);
        switchPanelScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        // first column
        c.gridx = 0;
        add(switchPanelScrollPane, c);

        // second column
        c.gridx = 1;

        // first row
        c.gridy = 0;

        // second row
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        add(btnPanel, c);

        btnPanel.add(new JButton(new AddSwitchAction("Add Switch Panel")));
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RF Connection Panel " + version);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new DrawPanelMain());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(false);
        //frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /*
    * AddSwitchAction will add a new pane to the tabbedPane when the add switch button is clicked
    */
    private class AddSwitchAction extends AbstractAction {
        public AddSwitchAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String title = "Switch ";
            DrawEllipses tabComponent = new DrawEllipses(POINT_LIST);
            switchPanel.add(title, tabComponent);

        }
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DrawEllipses extends JPanel {
    private final int PREF_W = 750; //Window width
    private final int PREF_H = 750; //Window height
    private final int OVAL_WIDTH = 30;
    private static final Color INACTIVE_COLOR = Color.RED;
    private static final Color ACTIVE_COLOR = Color.green;
    private java.util.List<Point> points;
    private java.util.List<Ellipse2D> ellipses = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<Ellipse2D, Color> ellipseColorMap = new HashMap<>();

    /*
     * This method is used to populate "ellipses" with the initialized ellipse2D dimensions
     */
    public DrawEllipses(java.util.List<Point> points) {
        this.points = points;
        for (Point p : points) {
            int x = p.x - OVAL_WIDTH / 2;
            int y = p.y - OVAL_WIDTH / 2;
            int w = OVAL_WIDTH;
            int h = OVAL_WIDTH;
            Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
            ellipses.add(ellipse);
            ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, INACTIVE_COLOR);
        }

        MyMouseAdapter mListener = new MyMouseAdapter();
        addMouseListener(mListener);
        addMouseMotionListener(mListener);
    }

    /*
     * paintComponent is used to paint the ellipses
     */
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // paints the background
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
            g2.setColor(ellipseColorMap.get(ellipse));
            g2.fill(ellipse);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
            g2.draw(ellipse);
        }

        /*
         * Set the font characteristics, color, and draw the row labels.
         */
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 18));
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        //Along the top row
        g.drawString("External Port", 10, 50);
        g.drawString("1", 135, 50);
        g.drawString("2", 195, 50);
        g.drawString("3", 255, 50);
        g.drawString("4", 315, 50);
        g.drawString("5", 375, 50);
        g.drawString("6", 435, 50);
        g.drawString("7", 495, 50);
        g.drawString("8", 555, 50);
        g.drawString("9", 615, 50);
        g.drawString("10", 672, 50);

        //Along the Y-axis
        g.drawString("Radio 2", 40, 145);
        g.drawString("3", 90, 205);
        g.drawString("4", 90, 265);
        g.drawString("5", 90, 325);
        g.drawString("6", 90, 385);
        g.drawString("7", 90, 445);
        g.drawString("8", 90, 505);
        g.drawString("9", 90, 565);
        g.drawString("10", 90, 625);

        //Along the X-Axis
        g.drawString("1", 135, 670);
        g.drawString("2", 195, 670);
        g.drawString("3", 255, 670);
        g.drawString("4", 315, 670);
        g.drawString("5", 375, 670);
        g.drawString("6", 435, 670);
        g.drawString("7", 495, 670);
        g.drawString("8", 555, 670);
        g.drawString("9", 615, 670);

        //Draws a 3DRect around the top row of ellipse2D objects
        g2.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        g2.draw3DRect(120, 60, 580, 40, true);
        g2.draw3DRect(121, 61, 578, 38, true);
        g2.draw3DRect(122, 62, 576, 36, true);

    }

    /*
     * MouseAdapter is extended for mousePressed Event that detects if the x, y coordinates
     * of a drawn ellipse are clicked.  If the color is INACTIVE it is changed to ACTIVE and
     * vice versa.
     */
    private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        /*
         * When mousePressed event occurs, the color is toggled between ACTIVE and INACTIVE
         */
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            Color c;
            for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
                if (ellipse.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                    c = (ellipseColorMap.get(ellipse) == INACTIVE_COLOR) ? ACTIVE_COLOR : INACTIVE_COLOR;
                    ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, c);
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    /*
* This method will set the dimensions of the JFrame equal to the preferred H x W
*/
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }


    /*
     * Used for button click action to change all ellipses to ACTIVE_COLOR
     */
    public void activateAll(){
        for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses){
            ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, ACTIVE_COLOR);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    /*
     * Used for button click action to change all ellipses to INACTIVE_COLOR
     */
    public void deactivateAll(){
        for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses){
            ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, INACTIVE_COLOR);
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: The only way people might help you is to run your code to see exactly what you are currently doing. I tried and it displayed  "tiny rectangle" because 1) your hard coded size is still too big for my monitor and 2) so the panel is displayed at its minimum size. Since you haven't implemented my suggest from your last question I can't run the code.

Comment: @camickr Please see the edit.

Answer (score 3):

As I suggested earlier if you want relative positioning then you need to calculate the relative location every time your paint (or when the component is resized).

Basically you know that widthwise you have 10 circle you want to paint at 30 pixels each and a label at a fixed width of say 100. So that means you have a minimum width of 400 pixels.

Of course that is not reasonable as you want a gap between each circle, so you need to decide what your preferred gap is and multiply that by 9 to determine your true minimum size. Looks like you have about a 30 pixel gap so that is another 270 pixels giving a preferred size of 670 pixels.

So the question is what do you do when the width is greater than 670? Do you increase the gap or leave it at 30?

The harder case is when the width is less than 670, as you will now need to adjust the gap smaller, down to some minimum value.

Once you determine the horizontal gap to use, you go through the same analysis for the vertical gap.

Now when you do your painting you have your starting location and every row you paint will be increased by your vertical gap. And every circle on the row will be increased by the horizontal gap.

I have never tried it but I believe you can use the `setFrame(...)` method of your Ellipse to dynamically move its location. So when you do your painting the Ellipse will no be in the correct spot and it should respond to mouse events correctly.

So basically you are writing your own custom layout manager for Graphics.

The second approach, instead of doing custom painting, is to use real components.

You can easily create a custom Icon to represent the circles. Then maybe you can use a JToggleButton. Then your logic of changing color can be handled by the toggle button and two different colored Icons.

Now the hard part. I have never tried it before, but I believe you can use the [Spring Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html).

`SpringLayout` positions components relative to one another. It also contains "springs" between the components to allow the gap to grow/shrink.

Those are the two approaches as I see it.